# Rails 4 form_tag update element with partial

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

In Rails 4 how do I adjust the below controller, view and partial view such that when I click the `"Update Time"` Submit button, the html div with id of `'search_results'` is updated with content generated by the `_results.html.erb` partial?

I have not used Rails in some time and I seem to remember it was extremely simple to do in Rails 1.  The documentation I am finding for Rails 4 seems to involve JQuery which I am not familiar with and do not understand how to tie it into this form.

I have had a read through this: http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html

But still do not entirely understand what is going on.

**RuleSearchController.rb**

```
class RuleSearchController < ApplicationController
  def index

  end

  def results

  end
end
```

**index.html.erb**

```
<%= form_tag('/rule_search_results', :id => 'search_form') do %>
  <%= submit_tag "Update Time" %>
<% end %>

<div id='search_results'>
  <%= render partial: "results" %>
</div>
```

**_results.html.erb**

```
<%= Time.new %>
```

**Update**
The current answer is doing some weird things.  It works when I have something in `_results.html.erb` which is a simple one liner like:

```
<%= Time.new %>
```

If however I do something as simple as this:

```
<%= Time.new %>
<hr />
```

Whilst there is no error coming up on the console, nothing happens and the  search results div is not updated.

**Further Update**
I can iterate an array of AR objects and have their name print in the search_results div provided I do it in one like like below and that it is the only line in the file:

```
<% for rule in rules do %><%= rule.name %><% end %>
```

The below however does not work

```
<% for rule in rules do %>
  <%= rule.name %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

**index.html.erb**

```
<%= form_tag('/rule_search_results', :id => 'search_form', remote: true) do %>
  <%= submit_tag "Update Time" %>
<% end %>
```

Then create a file called '***results.js.erb***' in the same directory as your _results.html.erb file with this:

```
$('#search_results').html('<%= render partial: "results" %>');
```

What this does is the remote: true tells the controller than it's a javascript request, and so the controller knows to look for the file with the method name followed by .js.erb and run the JS code automatically.

Update: In answer to the issues with multi-line HTML, you can add a 'j' before then render, and this will escape the output:

```
$('#search_results').html('<%= j render partial: "results" %>');
```

Comment: Thanks, that works great and is exactly what I need.  I really need to get into JS stuff and learn it properly, but I do not need much beyond this for what I am doing in rails now.  There was a missing parenthesis in your response, I edited it in case anyone searches this question later.

Comment: This answer is doing some weird things when the code in results.html.erb is not a simple one line, one html tag file.  Please see Update in question for details

Comment: I have remarked this as correct as it did do what I originally wanted, this perhaps warrants a separate question.

Comment: that is very cool for getting round the 1 line issue.  Cheers.