# Rails 4 JavaScript/JQuery update of partial only working for single line view.html.erb file

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a controller:

```
class RuleSearchController < ApplicationController
  def index

  end

  def results
    # Rule is a simple AR class with just a name column
    @rules = Rule.all
  end
end
```

I have a search form in `index.html.erb`:

```
<%= form_tag('/rule_search_results', :id => 'search_form', remote: true) do %>
  <%= submit_tag "Update" %>
<% end %>

<div id='search_results'>
  <%= render partial: "results" %>
</div>
```

I then have a results.js.erb as per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30395809/rails-4-form-tag-update-element-with-partial/30396474#30396474) with the addition of locals to pass my search results through.

```
$('#search_results').html('<%= render partial: "results", locals: {rules: @rules} %>');
```

The problem is that whilst the following works for the _results.html.erb file:

```
<ul><% for rule in rules do %><li><%= rule.name %></li><% end %></ul>
```

The following identical code but over several lines does not:

```
<ul>
<% for rule in rules do %>
  <li><%= rule.name %></li>
<% end %>
</ul>
```

In fact doing anything other than using a single line in the _results.html.erb file causes nothing to happen.  There is no error in the JS console on Chrome, no error on the terminal window the rails server is running, no errors in the logs, it just quietly does not work.

The problem occurs even on basic HTML, it does not help if I take the locals out.

**The solution / workaround is:**

```
$('#search_results').html('<%= (render partial: "results", locals: {rules: @rules}).gsub("\n","").html_safe %>');
```

Although the answer to my original question by neuronaut was correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because javascript doesn't allow strings to be split across multiple lines. For example, the following is valid javascript:

```
$('#search_results').html('<div>foo</div>');
```

But the following is not valid:

```
$('#search_results').html('<div>
foo
</div>');
```

If you've got the HTML in a partial why not just render it in the correct location in the first place, but set `display: none` for its style and then use jQuery to show the element later when you need it?

Comment: Thanks for explaining why the JS is doing that.  I cannot have have the element rendered in advance.  What I am trying to do is have a search form display its results in a div.  Something I remember being utterly trivial in Rails 1 (the last time I used Rails) but I cannot seem to find a similar simple way to do it in Rails 4

Comment: I have worked this out using .gsub and have posted that at the end of the question.

Comment: @Axiombadger If you are rendering a response from an ajax query then you could use jQuery's `load` function and avoid needing to manually display the result using the `html` function. e.g. `$('#some-div-id').load('http://url.to/get/the/data')` and the HTML returned by the call will be rendered directly into the specified element.

Comment: Thanks @neuronaut . . . I presume though I would have to send GET arguments through that rather than POST a form?

Comment: @Axiombadger not necessarily -- according to the jQuery docs: "The POST method is used if data is provided as an object; otherwise, GET is assumed." Which one you use is more up to what the server side expects, but either way I think you'd have to read the 2 values from the form fields to set up the call to `load`. See http://api.jquery.com/load/ for more details.